# Why is Databinding for a CheckedListBox "Hidden"?

Tags: c#, data-binding, checkedlistbox

The DataSource property on a CheckedListBox is hidden from Intellisense.  Why?  You can use the binding properties to make it work, but I'm worried that it's hidden for a reason and that I shouldn't be databinding on a CheckedListBox for some important reason that I'm not aware of.

Is databinding on a CheckedListBox ok??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`CheckedListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) is intended to be used with its [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection.add.aspx) and [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx) methods:

> To add objects to the list at run
>   time, assign an array of object
>   references with the `AddRange` method.
>   The list then displays the default
>   string value for each object. You can
>   add individual items to the list with
>   the `Add` method.

While data binding to the `CheckedListBox` may work you ought to avoid creating dependencies on anything but the public interface of a type.  I would recommend that you use the proper methods as this will make you code less brittle in the event that Microsoft changes the implementation of `CheckedListBox`.

Comment: This is due to the fact that `CheckedListBox` inherits those members from `Control`.  Certain aspects of data binding are still visible (most likely because they are still used under the covers).

Comment: Andrew Hare: Can you pls post a tiny example of how to databind with AddRange? All the examples are presented with a string array, not a datatable.