# difficulty inserting a name to an inserted object of a checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I am abit new in C# and i am trying to insert an object to a `CheckedListBox`,
so this inserted item will have a title inside the checked list (my object contains a string field inside it which I want to be displayed in the CheckedListBox).
for example this is my class:

```
 public class InfoLayer
{
    private string LayerName;
    private List<GeoInfo> GeoInfos;
    public InfoLayer()
    {
        LayerName = "New Empty Layer";
        GeoInfos = new List<GeoInfo>();
    }
    public InfoLayer(string LayerName)
    {
        this.LayerName = LayerName;
        GeoInfos = new List<GeoInfo>();
    }
    public InfoLayer(string LayerName,List<GeoInfo> GeoInfosToClone):this(LayerName)
    {
        foreach (GeoInfo item in GeoInfosToClone)
        { 
             GeoInfos.Add((GeoInfo)((ICloneable)item).Clone());
        }
    }
    public GeoInfo SearchElement(long id)
    {
        foreach (GeoInfo info in GeoInfos) // foreach loop running on the list 
        {
            if (info.INFOID == id) 
                return info; // return the item if we found it
        }
        return null;
    }

    public GeoInfo SearchElement(string name)
    {
        foreach (GeoInfo info in GeoInfos)
        {
            if (info.INFONAME.CompareTo(name)==0)
                return info;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string toReturn = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < GeoInfos.Count; i++) // for loop running on the list 
        {
            toReturn += String.Format("{0}\n",GeoInfos[i].ToString()); // piping another geoinfo 
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public string LAYERNAME{get{return LayerName;}}
```

my class also contains a tostring overrider inside her (not what i want to display)

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you show us some code of your try and class?

Comment: How would you like your new line to show in your CheckedListBox?

Comment: the name of the layer i can create a prop for it ... my class contains a string name field i will add the prop to the question

Comment: Your ToString() method will return a multiline string. Is that your intention?

Comment: indeed its for other use (the tostring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Override ToString() in your class, the class that the object is an instance of.</strike>

Edit:

You don't want to display the contents of `ToString()`. You want to display the `LayerName`, don't you? Perhaps you should display the values with Databinding instead. Then you can set `DisplayMember` to your new `LAYERNAME` property.

Comment: +1 I had misunderstood the question and your answer made it clear. =)

Comment: @Nadav: If ToString() doesn't work, then what text does show up in the CheckedListBox when you add your object?

Comment: Before you start to use databinding on the CheckedListBox, read up on this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346686/why-is-databinding-for-a-checkedlistbox-hidden

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(yourObject.stringField);
```

Comment: nope i want the list to contain the object and the checkbox to have the txt field of the object as a name. 
this would have been so easy if that was the case

Answer (score 0):

<strike>((MyObjectType)checkedListBox1.Items(index)).Name = "whatever"</strike>

You will have to know the index of the object you want to change.

You'll just have to override the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method in your class so that it returns this `Name` property value.

```
public overrides string ToString() {
    return Name;
}
```

It will then display its name when added to your `CheckedListbox`.

Comment: i dont want to change a field inside my object

Comment: i want the checkedlistbox to have next to the inserted item the name of the item which i will put

Comment: It would have been clearer to mention this in your question, if I may say so. =) Edited my answer.

Comment: my class already have a tostring override fuction but it doesnt work